# Is it possible to use functions declared in a shell flavor in another shell type

Tags: bash, shell-script, ksh, function

I have a bash script that contains many common functions definitions for our Linux system.

Is it possible to source it and use functions from another shell flavor (csh and ksh) ?

Comment: `csh` doesn't have functions. Use scripts instead of functions. Then you can decide which interpreter to use for each and can call them from any shell.

Comment: Yes . Stick to POSIX and if you must use non-POSIX features, test them on multiple shells and possibly write adaptors where they don't work (outside of POSIX, `local` is very portable). I have one larger shell project and it runs OK in like 7 shells.

Comment: The direction I've chosen , inspired by the answers, is to rewrite all cshell in bash (only a few survivors from another era on the system) and to adapt the functions sources so it can be interpreted by both ksh and bash. ATM only a few changes were a necessity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be easy enough to create a wrapper script around the functions; for Bash:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

doSomething()
{
    ...
}

doSomethingElse()
{
    ...
}

FUNCTION_NAME=$1
shift
${FUNCTION_NAME} "$@"

exit $?
```

Call:

```bsh
/path/to/functionWrapper.sh doSomething [<param1>] [...]
```

Comment: Good, but I think I'm stuck since I use in some function global variable to handle the return of a string value (not a very nice pattern, but I didn't found another proper way)

Comment: Well, a good reason to refactor... Try using temp files (or perhaps named pipes) instead - caller creates the temp file, passes the name as parameter and takes care of cleanup.

Answer (score 3):

In general, no.

In particular, `csh` (and `tcsh`) have a too different syntax from the `sh`-derived shells (`sh`, `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`), so they would most likely not understand a `sh` script, or vice versa.

The `sh` shells can sometimes share functions or even whole scripts, but only if they are written for the "smallest common denominator shell", which is usually `sh`.  This, however, is usually not a good idea.

Think of each shell as a separate scripting language, like Perl, Ruby and Python.  Don't mix them, and don't generally assume that one interpreter can understand the source of another.

Answer (score 3):

As  Stéphane Chazelas noted in the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400789/is-it-possible-to-use-functions-declared-in-a-shell-flavor-in-another-shell-type#comment715959_400789), `csh` and related `tcsh` do not have functions, hence you can't source the functions file you have anyway.

However, bourne-like shells often share syntax and functionality, and in fact `bash` borrowed a lot of functionality from `ksh`,  but some of the features these shells have aren't compatible with `dash` - a default shell on [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) and a closer one in behavior to original Bourne shell.

Another issue that comes up is not just about functions, but commands that functions might call. If you're using those functions on Ubuntu, and then suddenly go to FreeBSD, you'll quickly find out that utilities like `find` or `ps` often have options that either behave differently or missing.

So in order to make sure you can use functions, I would suggest two things: consider commands and portability of their options and two - write functions that stick to POSIX standard and original Bourne shell syntax as close as possible.

Alternatively, if you have the luxury to always  install the shell you want (which might not happen if you don't have `sudo` privileges on the system you're working), then write your functions in one specific shell's syntax.

See [When is it important to write portable scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119657/85039) for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

In specific for the C Shell, you cannot, since C Shell doesn't support functions. Apart that, C Shell uses different syntax. For example, the following C Shell snippets are different from what Bash would use.

```
if ( $days > 365 ) then
   echo This is over a year.
endif
```

```
set i = 2
set j = 1
while ( $j <= 10 )
   echo '2 **' $j = $i
   @ i *= 2
   @ j++
end
```